# Symfony CMF - How to retrieve current node in a controller

Tags: symfony, controller, routes, symfony-cmf

I'm trying to retrieve the route node in a Symfony CMF controller.

My route was created like :

```
$route = new MultilangRoute();
$route->setDefault('_controller', 'AcmeMainBundle:Demo:news');
$dm->persist($route);
```

How can I get the `MultilangRoute` route object in my `AcmeMainBundle:Demo:news` action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution with :

```
$request->attributes->get('_route')
```

Comment: the cmf router puts the route object into _route, instead of the route name like the core symfony router does.